Did Adam join Eve in disobedience to save her?
Adam was not with Eve when she ate the fruit Satan offered her. He did not hear the conversation, otherwise, God in His response would have said that Adam listened to the serpent, but God said that he listened to his wife.  Gen 3:17:

And unto Adam he said, Because thou hast hearkened unto the voice of thy wife, and hast eaten of the tree, of which I commanded thee, saying, Thou shalt not eat of it: cursed is the ground for thy sake; in sorrow shalt thou eat of it all the days of thy life;

This opinion is the basis for my understanding of this comparison. I do not wish to discuss this aspect of the situation. I state it here merely to illustrate my understanding of Genesis 3:6 and its translation, from which my question originates.
Gen 3:6:

And when the woman saw that the tree was good for food, and that it was pleasant to the eyes, and a tree to be desired to make one wise, she took of the fruit thereof, and did eat, and gave also unto her husband with her [?] and he did eat.

Just as Adam was not deceived, neither was Jesus deceived, Jesus did not sin.
Adam was not deceived but partook to help Eve.  1 Tim 2:14:

And Adam was not deceived, but the woman being deceived was in the transgression.

Jesus partook of flesh and blood to help us.
The Church is referred to as a Crown of thorns to Jesus in Prov 12:4, just as a wife is a crown to her husband:

A virtuous woman is a crown to her husband: but she that maketh ashamed is as rottenness in his bones.

The Bride of Christ is Jesus's "Crown" as I complete the comparison from John 19:5:

Then came Jesus forth, wearing the crown of thorns, and the purple robe. And Pilate saith unto them, Behold the man!

John 3:16:

For God so loved the world, that he gave his only begotten Son, that whosoever believeth in him should not perish, but have everlasting life.

Another observation: What other situation could Paul have been referring to when he referred to the "husband" as the savior or the marriage?  Ephesians 5:23 (KJV):

For the husband is the head of the wife, even as Christ is the head of the church: and he is the saviour of the body

This appears in all aspects to be accurate. Showing unnecessary deference to Eve/woman-kind by suggesting that Adam was "with her" at that time is merely an attempt to allude to a shared sense of guilt and does not justify distorting scripture, in my opinion.
Hence my question: Did Adam join Eve in disobedience to save her?

To brmicke: Intriquing typology you have there, wonder whether any church fathers ever interpret the verses you quoted that way, maybe allegorically.  As @RyanPierceWilliams said, it doesn't mesh well with the narrative, so would you consider rephrasing the Q in terms of asking whether there have been typological / allegorical interpretations about Adam joining Eve in her fault to prefigure Jesus saving the church?

I'm missing something. "Did Adam join Eve in disobedience to save her?" — In what way could Eve be saved by Adam's joining her? (E.g. If my wife committed a crime, it would never occur to me to commit the same crime in order to save her.)

Interesting to ponder what would have happened had Adam refused to join Eve in sin

I am trying in my understanding of Eph 5:23 to not assume anything. The verses are making a comparison of "Jesus and the believers" and "Husbands and wives", and the comparison does not end in 23 but is continued through verse 24.

Eve could not have been corrected/saved from God's judgment, apart from Adam. So He joined Her. If there is another explanation it is not apparent to me at this time.

Rather than live apart from Her , He bore Her sin and through grace Jesus in the future taught some of Eve's decendants to deny ungodliness. Again this does not assume anything . This conclusion simply  recognizes the outcome of the events. This is what Happened as a result of Adam, who while not being deceived Himself, knowingly entered into disobedience with Eve who was deceived.


Did Adam join Eve in disobedience to save her?

The short answer is no.

Wherefore, as by one man sin entered into the world, and death by sin; and so death passed upon all men, for that all have sinned: - Romans 5:12

The Bible is clear that sin and death, indeed the curse of God upon the very ground and the groaning of all creation comes as the result of Adam's disobedience not Eve's.

For Adam was first formed, then Eve. And Adam was not deceived, but the woman being deceived was in the transgression. - 1 Timothy 2:13-14

God created Adam and gave him command and consequence (eat not lest you die) before the creation of Eve.  A common understanding is that Eve learned of this command from Adam rather than directly from God.  Eve, therefore, was involved in the transgression but, had Adam not done that which was forbidden, there would have been nothing to save Eve from:  Sin and death entered through one man.

Notwithstanding she shall be saved in childbearing, if they continue in faith and charity and holiness with sobriety. - 1 Timothy 2:15

Eve needs salvation because of what Adam did.  He did not disobey to save her, his disobedience created her need for salvation.

You are suggesting that Eve's disobedience would not have been recognized as disobedience if Adam had not joined in. Being unaware that something is a sin does not make a person innocent, it simply means that they can be forgiven, as was the case with Paul in  1 Tim 1:13.  Citing 1 Tim 2:15 suggests a looking forward to faith in Christ. In this case, I feel also that Adam saw Christ's day just as Abraham did, John 8:56.

@brmicke I also think that Adam saw Christ's day but the promise only came after he sinned, not before.  What the scripture says is that sin and death entered through Adam not Eve.  What I am suggesting is the Federal Headship of the first and second Adam.

Did Adam join Eve in disobedience to save her?
The short answer is no.
In joining Eve in the sin of disobedience, Adam certainly did so out of a misplaced sense of companionship or as St. Augustine puts it: ”out of a certain friendly good-will!”

... But as regards the species of pride, the woman sinned more grievously, for three reasons. First, because she was more puffed up than the man. For the woman believed in the serpent's persuasive words, namely that God had forbidden them to eat of the tree, lest they should become like to Him; so that in wishing to attain to God's likeness by eating of the forbidden fruit, her pride rose to the height of desiring to obtain something against God's will. On the other hand, the man did not believe this to be true; wherefore he did not wish to attain to God's likeness against God's will: but his pride consisted in wishing to attain thereto by his own power. Secondly, the woman not only herself sinned, but suggested sin to the man; wherefore she sinned against both God and her neighbor. Thirdly, the man's sin was diminished by the fact that, as Augustine says (Gen. ad lit. xi, 42), "he consented to the sin out of a certain friendly good-will, on account of which a man sometimes will offend God rather than make an enemy of his friend. That he ought not to have done so is shown by the just issue of the Divine sentence."
It is therefore evident that the woman's sin was more grievous than the man's.
ST II-II, Q.163, A.4, co. (Whether Adam's sin was more grievous than Eve's?)

In Genesis, God specifically told Adam (not Eve) that the entire earth was cursed because Adam had allowed Eve to persuade him to eat of the fruit, and also that he would die (Genesis 3:17-19).
Yet St. Thomas Aquinas states in his Summa that Adam was responsible for transmitting Original sin to the entire human race and not Eve:

The solution of this question is made clear by what has been said. For it has been stated (Article 1) that original sin is transmitted by the first parent in so far as he is the mover in the begetting of his children: wherefore it has been said (Article 4) that if anyone were begotten materially only, of human flesh, they would not contract original sin. Now it is evident that in the opinion of philosophers, the active principle of generation is from the father, while the mother provides the matter. Therefore original sin, is contracted, not from the mother, but from the father: so that, accordingly, if Eve, and not Adam, had sinned, their children would not contract original sin: whereas, if Adam, and not Eve, had sinned, they would contract it.
ST I-II, Q.81, A.5 co. (Whether if Eve, and not Adam, had sinned, their children would have contracted original sin?)

